# OSError: [WinError 123] La syntaxe du nom de fichier, de répertoire ou de volume est incorrecte: '<frozen importlib._bootstrap>'

Tags: python, django

I have an error but did know why and how to resolve

I start a new projects and use code of my previous project for authentification

I install all dependencies Problem come form 2 dependencies crispy_forms and boostrap4 I already use in the same way

As you can see in the settings.py below, crispy_forms and boostrap4 are declared in apps

My virtual env is active and I have install all dependencies in this environnement

If I deactivate the 'crispy_forms' and 'bootstrap4' in INSTALLED_APP, my home page can be display but error raised if I try to display the login page (error: 'crispy_forms_tags' is not a registered tag library)

settings.py

```
"""
Django settings for mereva project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.0.6.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'rc_oh(6&d$)jin3txiiiqvuw2+-mla*f^em9!=yzlgx_o^mph9'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    'crispy_forms',
    'widget_tweaks',
    'bootstrap4',

    'registration.apps.RegistrationConfig',
    'parameters.apps.ParametersConfig',

    'debug_toolbar',
    'partial_date',
    'safedelete',
    'simple_history',
]

CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap4'

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',

    'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',

    'simple_history.middleware.HistoryRequestMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'mereva.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'registration/templates'),
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates'),
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mereva.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static'),
)

LOGIN_URL = 'home'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'home'
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = 'home'
```

Comment: Please review your project apps structure. Import errors often indicate that there is `__init__.py` missing

Comment: What I Do is django-admin startproject and in this project I copy/paste folders registration (authentification module) and then py manage.py makemigrations/migrate

Comment: If you are copying some apps from other project then you probably should remove `__pycache___` folders especially if Python runtimes are different

Comment: I remove all __pycache__ folders but still have the same error

Comment: Can you add full stack trace of an exception? The problem here is that  something is trying to access file named `<frozen importlib._bootstrap>` but this is not a valid name on Windows (as you get WinError 123)

Comment: I resolve the problem using Django 2.2.5 instead of 3

Answer (score 1):

You need to check those template tags can be imported without errors like example below:-

```
python manage.py shell
```

After entering the django shell try running:

```
from crispy_forms.templatetags import crispy_forms_tags
```

If you do not get any errors then most likely you have forgotten to import them into your templates like:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load staticfiles %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
```

If you have got errors while importing then your `crispy_forms` package is either missing those template tags or having version compatibility problem which is unlikely. And well in that case you can try reinstalling them.

Comment: thanks for replying, as said above, the problem come from django version ; I use Django 2.2.5 until now (in my previous project) and install Django 3.0 in my new project...